# Setting a variable via echo somtimes adds a random ' at the end

Tags: azure-devops

I have a bash script with the following functionality:

```
# usage: setOutput <name> <value>
function setOutput {
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$1]$2"
}

setOutput environment "dev"
```

This normally sets the variable correctly as `ENVIRONMENT=dev` - however, sometimes this randomly appends a `'` at the end, i.e. `ENVIRONMENT=dev'`

I tried re-running the same commit on the pipeline multiple times, and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the fact that @Hugh Lin - MSFT could not reproduce the issue, I looked a littel closer and found out, what was actually going wrong:

---

In the beginning of my script, I used:

```
set -ex
```

This lead to there beeing two echos:

```
+echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=key]value'
##vso[task.setvariable variable=key]value
```

Depending on the order of the two (since the first is written to stderr, the second one to stdout), sometimes the value was set to the correct value, and somtimes to the debug echo one. And since that one has the addition `'` at the end, so does the exported output.

My suggestion: Only process stdout for these echo commands, not stderr, or add a special filter for `set -x`. I removed the debug output and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with your sample, it can be displayed normally .

[image]

You can try to remove the double quotes of `dev` to see if this will happen.

```
function setOutput {
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$1]$2"
}

setOutput environment dev
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found out what was going wrong. See the answer I posted